# Power of True Restoration in Magic Item?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, magic-items, published-adventures

In the adventure **Dragon's Delve Level 7: Sprawl of the Demon Liege**, Room 185, the characters can gain a **Magical Candlestick** that has the power of *true restoration* (CL 16), which can be activated once.

I am not sure if this should be, say, the 9th level cleric spell *True Resurrection*, 7th level *Restoration Greater*, 4th level *Restoration* or may be another spell I am unaware of.

The adventure is not specially a party-level adventure as the design is meant for a group that comes and gos over the campaign, but does have EL of between 5 and 13.

Which spell is likely the correct one for this item?

Comment: Does the adventure list the cost of the item? I know at least Pathfinder has a formula for the price of items that replicate spells.

Comment: nope as the items are unsellable.

Comment: "Further, this power is only usable by the character that takes them out of the room, so they have no resale value."

Comment: I guess True Resurrection is out as you can't cast a 9th level spell at Caster Level 16 (but magic Item CL doesn't have to be be the same as creator's level)

Comment: Unless Errata exists, I don't think that this question can be definitively answered; any answer would be almost exclusively conjecture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My feeling is that the author just got the names messed up, and was aiming for Greater Restoration.

True Resurrection seems too powerful and as has been outlined already needs to be at least CL 17th.

The standard Restoration would probably just be termed Restoration in the text, without the need to add a 'True' in there.

Disclaimer: I am in this adventure

Comment: This is a reasonable circumstantial argument, but “True Resurrection […] needs to be at least CL 17th” is… a problematic statement. The magic item creation rules specify that a magic item must have at least the minimum caster level for a spell it casts, only… the spellcasting rules **never define any minimum caster level**. From examples, the minimum caster level used is the “default” for when you get that level of spells, but that’s a lot of extrapolation. And, well, if a 17th-level cleric took a −1 penalty to caster level, that should **not** stop them from casting *true resurrection*.

Comment: I would say that using this standard for caster level, while not hard enforced by the rules, is sufficiently consistent that it's worth using as a basis for extrapolation. I admit "needs" might not be the right word, but something along the lines of "would/should have been" is more than warranted.